# How to run multiple instances of one object

Tags: javascript, oop, html5-canvas

I am very new to OOP Javascript, and I am trying to learn by building a game. In the game, you are basically a square, and other square are coming at you from the right. Sounds easy. You can basically avoid them by moving up or down, if they touch you, you die. I have made a Player object as such:

```
function Player() {
this.color = "#0f0";
this.posx = canvas.width / 5;
this.posy = canvas.height / 2;
this.width = canvas.width / 23;
this.height = this.width;
this.jetpack = false;
this.speed = 7;

this.draw = function() {
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.fillRect(this.posx, this.posy, this.width, this.height);
}

this.fly = function() {
    if (this.jetpack == true) {
        this.posy -= this.speed;
    } else {
        this.posy += this.speed * 1.5;
    }

    if (this.posy >= canvas.height - this.height) {
        this.posy = canvas.height - this.height;
    }

    if (this.posy <= 0) {
        this.posy = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Then I can just define it with

```
var player = new Player();
```

That works just fine.

I have one main function that is basically an interval, which runs 30 times a second, that repeats the following code:

```
context.fillStyle = "#000";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

player.draw();
player.fly();
```

This draws the player and lets you move it just fine.
The problem comes with the enemies. I have the Enemy object defined as such:

```
function Enemy(posy) {
this.color = "#f00";
this.posy = posy;
this.posx = canvas.width;
this.width = canvas.width / 23;
this.height = this.width;
this.speed = 5;

this.draw = function() {
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.fillRect(this.posx, this.posy, this.width, this.height);
}

this.move = function() {
    this.posx -= this.speed;
}
}
```

But i dont know how to properly summon it. The goal is that it spawns a new one every second or so, and they all move. I dont know how to do it.. It has been hard to find help online, since I dont even really know how it is called, thus, I am not sure of what I should search for and how to properly formulate my ideas. I hope that this is clear enough tho...

Comment: If you're learning OOP why not give [ECMA 2015 Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) a shot?

Comment: @vladkras It's probably best to stick with non-class prototypal JavaScript first before learning classes, so they can understand the pros and cons. There is a lot of debate as to whether using classes in JavaScript is actually a good thing or not.

Comment: @samanime, it's 2018 and you don't actually need to waste time with canonical syntax to create react or whatever apps (but you must know what prototypes are if you learn js of course)

Comment: @vladkras It's not about "wasting time with syntax". There are some fundamental differences between [prototypal and classical inheritence](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-s-the-difference-between-class-prototypal-inheritance-e4cd0a7562e9) which is masked by the class syntax. They have strengths and weaknesses and it's good to know both. Prototypal syntax has a lot of strengths that you don't get with classical, like mixins.

Comment: @samanime, yes, a lot of strengths you don't need to create cool apps (to know != to code)

Comment: @vladkras This'll be my last comment on this subject because it's diverging off topic, but writing off strengths of a language means you don't know if you'll need them or not. The prototypal syntax of JavaScript makes it a lot more powerful in many cases then classes, and they can be especially useful in a web-based context. If you're learning JS (or anything), you might as well not half-ass it and learn it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you'll create an enemy the same as the player:

```
const enemy = new Enemy(123); // change 123 to a random value
```

What you'll want to do though is place those enemies into an array when you create them:

```
// make sure this is in an appropriate place to maintain proper context
// probably the same level you define your player variable
const enemies = []; 

function addEnemy() {
  enemies.push(new Enemy(Math.random() * screenHeight)); // screenHeight will be whatever the max height for them to spawn is.
}
```

This will then let you loop over the function and move them all:

```
enemies.forEach(enemy => enemy.move());
```

At some point, you'll also want to remove the enemies (either when they hit something or get off the screen), which you'll want to use `splice()` for:

```
enemies.splice(indexOfEnemyToRemove, 1);
```